# Python to dynamically build JSON with sub arrays

Tags: python, json, dynamic

I can build JSON from simple dictionary {} and List [], but when I try to build more complex structures.  I get '\' embedded in the output JSON.

The structure I want:

```
{"name": "alpha",
 "results": [{"entry1": 
        [
        {"sub1": "one"}, 
        {"sub2": "two"}
        ]
    }, 
    {"entry2": 
        [
        {"sub1": "one"}, 
        {"sub2": "two"}
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This is what I get:

```
   {'name': 'alpha',
    'results': '[{"entry1": "[{\\\\"sub1\\": \\\\"one\\\\"}, {\\\\"sub2\\\\": '
            '\\\\"two\\\\"}]"}, {"entry2": "[{\\\\"sub1\\\\": \\\\"one\\\\"}, 
    {\\\\"sub2\\\\": '
            '\\\\"two\\\\"}]"}]'}
```

Note the embedded \\. Every time the code goes through json.dumps another \ is appended.

Here's code that almost works, but doesn't:

```
import json
import pprint
testJSON = {}

testJSON["name"] = "alpha"

#build sub entry List
entry1List = []
entry2List = []
topList = []
a1 = {}
a2 = {}
a1["sub1"] = "one"
a2["sub2"] = "two"

entry1List.append(a1)
entry1List.append(a2)

entry2List.append(a1)
entry2List.append(a2)

# build sub entry JSON values for Top List
tmpDict1 = {}
tmpDict2 = {}
tmpDict1["entry1"] = json.dumps(entry1List)
tmpDict2["entry2"] = json.dumps(entry2List)
topList.append(tmpDict1)
topList.append(tmpDict2)

# Now lets' add the List with 2 sub List to the JSON
testJSON["results"] = json.dumps(topList)

pprint.pprint (testJSON)
```

Comment: You're embedding encoded JSON into a dict and then re-encoding the already-encoded JSON. If you want to "merge" JSON, just "merge" the dicts

Comment: Simply: build your data first in form of Pyhon dict or list, and finally convert it to JSON using `json.dumps(data)`. JSON is not special data type, it is serialization method representing some data in form of a string.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line:

`tmpDict1["entry1"] = json.dumps(entry1List)`

This is specifying that key entry1 have the value of the *string output* of converting entry1List to json.  In essence, it's putting JSON in a JSON string, so it's escaped.    To nest the datastructure, I'd go with:

`tmpDict1["entry1"] = entry1List`

Same with the other places.  Once there is a tree of lists and dicts - you should only need to call `json.dumps()` once on the root container (either a dict or a list).

Comment: Ah!  Makes sense - my usage pattern was wrong.  Thank you for the clarification.  I'll redo my approach.

Comment: Tested it out - worked great.  So build the structure 1st and then use the json.dumps() function.  thanks for the insight.